# Why spring mvc automatically add GsonHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: spring-mvc, gson

I want use Gson in my web application.When I config GsonHttpMessageConverter in webConfig Which extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter,I found a strang problem，that is before I add GsonHttpMessageConverter to converters in extendMessageConverters,there is already one in converters,and this one does not have config date style.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K8Qz.png)
why this happen?
I want a GsonHttpMessageConverter which have my date style "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring [automatically creates](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L820) a [`GsonHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.html) if it detects that Gson is in the classpath.

To customize the converter by creating your own, you can override the following method in [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html#configureMessageConverters-java.util.List-):

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    gsonHttpMessageConverter.setGson(gson);
    converters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);
}
```

Comment: You help me!Thanks very much!